# Spurious warning about binding temporary to reference member in constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, object-lifetime

I understand that if a temporary is bound to a reference member in the constructor's initializer list, the object will be destroyed as the constructor returns.

**However**, consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using callback_func = std::function<int(void)>;

int
func(const callback_func& callback)
{
  struct wrapper
  {
    const callback_func& w_cb;
    wrapper(const callback_func& cb) : w_cb {cb} { }
    int call() { return this->w_cb() + this->w_cb(); }
  };
  wrapper wrp {callback};
  return wrp.call();
}

int
main()
{
  std::cout << func([](){ return 21; }) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This looks perfectly valid to me.  The `callback` object will live during the whole execution of the `func` function and no temporary copy should be made for `wrapper`'s constructor.

Indeed, **GCC 4.9.0** compiles fine with all warnings enabled.

However, **GCC 4.8.2** compiler gives me the following warning:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -W main.cpp 
main.cpp: In constructor ‘func(const callback_func&)::wrapper::wrapper(const callback_func&)’:
main.cpp:12:48: warning: a temporary bound to ‘func(const callback_func&)::wrapper::w_cb’ only persists until the constructor exits [-Wextra]
     wrapper(const callback_func& cb) : w_cb {cb} { }
                                            ^
```

**Is this a false positive or am I misunderstanding the object lifetimes?**

Here are my exact compiler versions tested:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.9.0 20140604 (prerelease)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Turning off optimizations gives me a seg fault. Valgrind points out that the problem is somewhere around `func(std::function<int ()> const&)::wrapper::call()`.

Comment: Using `w_cb {cb}` results in segmentation violation for me. Using `w_cb(cb)` doesn't suffer from the same problem. Tested in g++ 4.8.3.

Comment: I could reproduce the Valgrind error with GCC 4.8.2. (Not a segfault, tough, the program outputs 42 and exits successfully as expected.) The executable produced by GCC 4.9.0 is Valgrind-clean. These observations don't change with different optimization levels.

Comment: I was shocked to hear it failed on some systems.  FWIW, works fine on ideone's default settings (GCC 4.8.1, with `{cb}`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a bug in gcc 4.8 that has been fixed in 4.9.  Here is the bug report:

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50025

Comment: The fact that the bug is not the *warning*, but rather what the *warning* is warning you about, would be useful.  I had to go to the link to determine that...  Ie, a temporary is actually created in gcc 4.8 and it doesn't last long enough.  Optimizations may cause the temporary to be elided out of existence?

Comment: Yes, this explains what is going on. Thanks for the link. I did some further research inspired by it and will post it as an answer but I'll accept yours.

Comment: It was a bug in the standard, and GCC was implementing the precise wording of the standard, which _required_ a temporary to be created there. DR 1288 fixed the standard.

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by Howard Hinnant and already indicated by R Sahu's comment, this is a bug (which used to be required by the then-broken standard; thanks to Tony D for pointing this out) in the way GCC 4.8 is treating initializer lists.

Changing the constructor in my original example from

```cpp
wrapper(const callback_func& cb) : w_cb {cb} { }
```

to

```cpp
wrapper(const callback_func& cb) : w_cb (cb) { }
```

makes the warning with GCC 4.8.3 go away and the created executable Valgrind clean.  The diff of the two assembly files is huge so I don't post it here.  GCC 4.9.0 creates identical assembly code for both versions.

Next, I replaced the `std::function` with a user-defined struct and deleted copy and move constructors and assignment operators.  Indeed, with GCC 4.8.3, this retains the warning but now also gives a (slightly more helpful) error that the above line of code calls the deleted copy constructor of the struct. As expected, there is no difference with GCC 4.9.0.